# How do I split a large table into a smaller multiple tables using mysql command line tool?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql table that I want to split into smaller tables. I want to break up the data in ranges like 1 - 199 and 200 - 299 and put them in new tables. How would I go about doing this from the mysql command line tool?

Comment: Just out of interest, *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: The table is a list of profile numbers that coincide with a product. In my case 0 - 199 is casing(wood trim) profiles, 200 - 299 is base profiles and so on. So I figure that it's better for each category to have it's own table. Instead of loading the entire table each time, when all I want is just the casing. Your thoughts?

Comment: @ghostz00 Hard to know without knowing more about the various schemas involved. However, from what you've said the existing table is being used to store un-related items (i.e.: a casing != base profile?), so it sounds like you're doing the right thing™ in the grand scheme of things. :-)

Comment: Do ***NOT*** do this - one table is better than multiple ones.  Add a type code if you need to distinguish between records.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - From the sounds of it, the table is currently a bit of a dump of miscellaneous un-related entries. If this is case, why would you not recommend creating dedicated tables?

Comment: @ghostz00 To clarify, it is likely that an higher level object uses multiple entries from the existing table? (i.e.: Might a "product" link  to a "casing profile" and also to a "base profile", etc.?)

Comment: @middaparka No, they aren't related at all.

Comment: @ghostz00 So they're all effectively "product attributes"? (If that's the case, then **leave it as-is as @OMG Ponies advises**.) Hmm.. you might want to update your question with a bit more background detail. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would simply be to use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to export the existing table schema and data. (I'd recommend using the "--complete-insert" option.)

You could then manually edit the resultant file, by adding the relevant table creation statements and editing the INSERT lines to use the appropriate table name.

Incidentally:

1. Whilst it might not be relevant, beware of data being added to the original table whilst you're carrying out the editing, etc.
2. If this all sounds a bit manual and painful, that's because it is. However, you have a fairly odd requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

figure out the max range, say it's 10000

```
for i in $(seq 0 100 10000) ; do 
   echo "create table Table$i like MyTable" | mysql mydb
   echo "insert into Table$i select * from MyTable where id >=$i and id < $(($i+100))" | mysql mydb
done
```

However, **do not do this**. There's hardly any reason for breaking up data like this, it'll only serve to make querying harder, adminstration harder, whoever(which might be you) is going to maintain your database/application will eventually go mad.